# Происходит обнуление вместо NULL при чтении из файла (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте, только начинаю пробовать MySQL.

Делаю запись из файла в таблицу. Последний столбец таблицы - дата (DATE). 
По идее (по руководству), она должна быть NULL, но у меня почему-то получается просто зануленная дата. Но при этом первая и последняя строки в столбце NULL, как и должно быть.

**В чем ошибка? Как ее исправить?**
 Почему первая и последняя строки NULL, а остальные просто обнулились?

*Server version: 5.5.23 MySQL Community Server (GPL)*

Текст в файле:

```
Fluffy  Harold  cat f   1993-02-04  \N
Claws   Gwen    cat m   1994-03-17  \N
Buffy   Harold  dog f   1989-05-13  \N
Fang    Benny   dog m   1990-08-27  \N
Bowser  Diane   dog m   1989-08-31  1995-07-29
Chirpy  Gwen    bird    f   1998-09-11  \N
Whistler    Gwen    bird    \N  1997-12-09  \N
Slim    Benny   snake   m   1996-04-29  \N
Kysia   Maria   cat f   1997-09-14  \N
```

Получилось в итоге так:
[image: Результат чтения из файла]

В примере руководства получается так:
[image: То, что должно было получиться по руководству]

Добавила структуру таблицы:
[image: структура таблица]

Comment: Оригинальный однако загрузчик ... Я бы просто заменил `update pet set death=NULL where death='0000-00-00'` после загрузки

Comment: версия mysql и структура таблицы плз.

Comment: А попробуйте сделать по науке: во-первых, указать в `LOAD DATA INFILE` точный список загружаемых полей, во-вторых, указать опции загрузки (разделители и пр.), в третьих, выполнить явную конвертацию в секции SET. И вообще - код всегда следует доводить до состояния, когда его выполнение не приводит к предупреждениям. Ну и сами предупреждения надо бы посмотреть - там бывает чего полезного...

Comment: @АлександрБелинский 5.5.23 MySQL Community Server (GPL), в пост добавила скрин структуры таблицы

Comment: @Akina Попробовала сделать первые два пункта (не знаю, правильно ли) `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/MySQLPractice/menagerie/pet.txt' INTO TABLE pet FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' (name, owner, species, sex, birth, death);`
(У меня еще проблема с тем, что я не знаю, где должен находиться текстовый файл, чтобы без указания пути читалось)
Третий пункт не совсем поняла что и как сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте значения по умолчанию для столбца с DATE, скорее всего там стоит "0000-00-00", замените на NULL.

По поводу разницы в записи значений из файла (часть в NULL, часть в "0000-00-00" сложно сказать по имеющимся данных, нужно больше информации. При выыполнении вашего запроса MySQL выдает 7 warnings, скорее всего в этом дело (количество записей, которые не NULL). Смотрите лог ошибок MySQL, там должно быть объяснение причин.

Comment: По умолчанию стоит NULL во всех стобцах.

Comment: @setchan тогда значения "0000-00-00" явно добавляются из-за некорректного запроса. смотрите лог, у вас на 9 записей как раз 7 предупреждений.

Comment: Как мне его посмотреть и что именно нужно там искать?

Comment: @setchan я не знаю где именно развернут у вас MySQL, но традиционно на Linux логи MySQL находятся в каталоге /var/log/mysql, смотрите лог ошибок, там при каждом выполнении вашего запроса должны генерироваться 7 warnings